# Fetching data from one component to another via services and rendering in html component

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch the data from admin-new.component.ts to admin-card.component.ts........The issue is that I am able to see my data in the console but when I try to render it in the HTML component inside the bootstrap card it fails

Here is the link to the screenshot

**https://ibb.co/5vsBvZs**

admin-new.component.ts

```js
export class AdminNewComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('f') form:NgForm
   categories
   default="Bread"
   constructor(public iservice:ItemsService,private 
   prservice:ProductsService,private router:Router,private 
   route:ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(items=>{
      console.log(items)
      this.categories=items
      })
    }
    onsubmit(f){
       //console.log(f)

       this.prservice.fetchintocardcomponent(f)
       this.router.navigate(['admin/products/new/card'])
     }

 }
```

products.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

cardsdatails:any[]=[]

   constructor() { }

   fetchproducts=new BehaviorSubject<any>(1);

   fetchintocardcomponent(data){
      this.cardsdatails.push(data);
      this.fetchproducts.next(this.cardsdatails.slice());
   }

}
```

admin-card.component.ts

```js
export class AdminCardComponent implements OnInit {

   subscription:Subscription
   pvalue

   constructor(private prservice:ProductsService,private 
   route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription=this.prservice.fetchproducts.subscribe((data=>{
      this.pvalue=data
      console.log(this.pvalue) //here i m seeing the output in the 
      }))

   }

 }
```

html component where the data is not being rendered

```html
 <mdb-card>
   <div class="view rgba-white-slight waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
     <mdb-card-img src="{{pvalue?.imageurl}}" alt="Card image cap"></mdb- 
       card-img>
     <a>
      <div class="mask"></div>
     </a>
   </div>
   <mdb-card-body>
     <mdb-card-title>
       <h4>{{pvalue.title}}</h4>
     </mdb-card-title>

     <mdb-card-text> 
       {{pvalue.price}}
     </mdb-card-text>

   </mdb-card-body>
 </mdb-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pvalue` is an array (as seen from `console.log(this.pvalue)`). So you need to loop over it (using *ngFor) or take first element of it (if you want just that):

```
<mdb-card>
  <div class="view rgba-white-slight waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
    <mdb-card-img src="{{pvalue[0]?.imageurl}}" alt="Card image cap"></mdb-card-img>
    <a>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <mdb-card-body>
    <mdb-card-title>
      <h4>{{pvalue[0]?.title}}</h4>
    </mdb-card-title>
    <mdb-card-text> 
      {{pvalue[0]?.price}}
    </mdb-card-text>
  </mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
```